# What's the android intent to show up the localization settings?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm sure this can be answered really easily. I just do not find the intent id for this job.

I want to show up that localization settings page, where the user can select "turn on localization through wifi..."

```
      Intent intent = new Intent( ??? );
      startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
```